# Show: $\lnot F \rightarrow G, F \rightarrow H \vdash G ∨ H$

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, natural-deduction

I'm having trouble attempting to prove the above argument. What assumption of $F$ can be made in order to obtain either $H$ or $G$ and still be properly discharged?

Everything I've tried so far gives me an assumption of $F$ that I'm not able to discharge...

Comment: You want to prove this with [Natural deduction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_deduction)?

Comment: You have to use $\lnot F \lor F$.

Comment: @Manx Yes, sorry that wasn't clear.

Comment: Apply [Disjunction elimination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjunction_elimination) to $\lnot F \lor F$.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Is that by introducing a disjunction and then performing an elimination? I don't get how you get the disjunction and then are able to discharge the original assumption of F

Comment: Prove $F\lor \neg F$ first, assume $F,\neg F$ then try to get $G\lor H$ with $\to$ Elim from the assumption, finally apply $\lor$ Elim on them you get $G\lor H$

Comment: @Manx but you have to assume F to get $F\lor\lnot F$, so how do you discharge this first assumption of F?

Comment: You can assume $\neg(F\lor \neg F)$ then find a contradiction, for example assume $F$ by $\lor$ Intro you get $(F\lor \neg F)$ so $\neg F$, assume $\neg F$ the same you get $(F\lor \neg F)$ so $F$ which is a contradiction, hence we have $F\lor \neg F$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:**

This could be one approach of the proof:

See if you can fill the missing steps

$$\def\fitch#1#2{\quad\begin{array}{|l}#1\\\hline#2\end{array}}
\fitch{~1.~~\neg F\to G\\~2.~~F\to H}{\fitch{~3.~~\neg(F\lor\neg F)}{\fitch{~4.~~F}{~5.~~F\lor\neg F&\lor\text{Intro}~4\\~6.~~\bot&\bot\text{Intro}~3,5}\\~7.\\\fitch{~8.~~\neg F}{~9.~~F\lor\neg F&\lor\text{Intro}~8\\~10.~~\bot&\bot\text{Intro}~3,9}\\~11.\\~12.}\\~13.\\\fitch{~14.~~F}{~15.~~H&\to\text{Elim}~2,14\\~16.~~G\lor H&\lor\text{Intro}~15}\\\fitch{~17.~~\neg F}{~18.~~G&\to\text{Elim}~1,17\\~19.~~G\lor H&\lor\text{Intro}~18}\\~20.}$$

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are working with a fairly standard natural deduction system with subproofs, you have two main strategies here:

First, do what Max does. This is the 'intuitive' approach ... the 'cleaner' of the two.

Second, do a Proof by Contradiction directly on the Conclusion, i.e. assume $\neg (G \lor H)$. That typically leads to a contradiction a little more quickly ... but it isn't as intuitive:

[image]

Comment: What software or website do you use for this format?

Comment: It's called 'Fitch' ... it comes with the book "Language, Proof, and Logic" ... the online version of which costs $55.  But, there actually is an online version as well: https://proofmood.mindconnect.cc/en/Fitch/fitch.php

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Manx and Bram28 for the help. I'm not sure why but I just had particular difficulties with assuming $¬(F\lor \lnot F)$ and deriving $(F\lor \lnot F)$.

Here is my answer

[image: natural deduction]

Comment: That is okay.  However, you can streamline it a bit.  Once you derive $\neg F$ on line 7 there is no need to assume it. You can **immediately** use *disjunction introduction* to infer $F\vee \neg F$, and thence use *negation elimination* to derive falsum ($\bot$).

Comment: $$\tiny\def\fitch#1#2{~~~~\begin{array}{|l}#1\\\hline#2\end{array}}\fitch{~~~~\vdots}{\fitch{~~3.~\neg (F\vee\neg F)}{\fitch{~~4.~F}{~~5.~F\vee\neg F\\~~6.~\bot}\\~~7.~\neg F\\~~8.~F\vee\neg F\\~~9.~\bot}\\10.~\neg\neg(F\vee\neg F)\\11.~F\vee\neg F\\~~~~\vdots}$$ This is the bog standard proof for LEM using DNE. ( Notice also how  Bram28's answer shares the same skeleton. )